# How to draw a pixels on PDF page using PDFsharp?

Tags: c#, .net, pdfsharp

I want to draw pixels on PDF files randomly. I am using PDFsharp to create a PDF file. But I didn't get pixel draw option in PDFsharp. Is there any way to draw a pixel on PDF file using PDFsharp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDF files do not have pixels (it's a vector format).

You can draw lines, circles, rectangles - or add a bitmap that only contains a pixel.

Answer (score 1):

This is a variation of what I do.

```
        #region Helper that adds a rectangle to coordinates. Helps visualize container. Uncomment to see extents of container 'rect'.

        XPen pen = new XPen(XColors.Black, 1);

        gfx.DrawRectangle(pen, 0, 0, 0, 1.0);

        #endregion
```

It creates a rectangle of size one pixel

You can also draw a line of length one pixel.